# LISP dynamically define functions

Tags: function, lisp, definition

I want to define a function with a parameter that defines another function with that parameter as the name.

example that dont work:

```
(DEFUN custom (name op const var)
  (DEFUN name (var) (op const var)))
```

The problem is that name isnt evaluated and so the function that is defined is always called name.

I know that `FUNCALL` and `APPLY` can evaluate parameter dynamically, but i don't know how to call `FUNCALL` `DEFUN...` correctly.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you want to use this? Actual code would be best.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can use nested defuns.

You can either use a [`defun`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defun.htm) to return a [`lambda`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_lambda.htm):

```
(defun custom (op const) 
  (lambda (arg) (funcall op const arg)))
```

and then use [`fdefinition`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_fdefin.htm):

```
(setf (fdefinition '+42) (custom '+ '42))
```

or use [`defmacro`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defmac.htm):

```
(defmacro custom (name op const)
  (let ((arg (gensym)))
    `(defun ,name (,arg)
       (,op ,const ,arg))))

(custom +42 + 42)
```

PS. I think you need to explain why you are trying to do this, then we will be able to explain your options better.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me you might want to curry a function. Imagine you did this:

```
(defun curry (op arg1)
  (lambda (&rest args) (apply op (cons arg1 args))))

(funcall (curry #'+ 10) 20)        ; ==> 30 

(mapcar (curry #'+ 10) '(1 2 3 4)) ; ==> (11 12 13 14)
```

Now `defun` makes a function in the global namespace always. It's not like in Scheme where it creates a closure. To do the same as `defun` we use `symbol-function` and `setf`:

```
(defun create-curried (name op arg1)
  (setf (symbol-function name) 
        (lambda (&rest args) (apply op (cons arg1 args)))))

(create-curried '+x #'+ 10) ; ==> function
(+x 20)                     ; ==> 30

;; since it's a function, it even works with higher order functions
(mapcar create-curried '(+x -x /x *x) (list #'+ #'- #'/ #'*) '(10 10 10 10))
(/x 2) ; ==> 5
```

Last. With macros you can prettify it.

```
(defmacro defun-curried (newname oldname arg)
  (if (and (symbolp newname) (symbolp oldname))
      `(create-curried ',newname (function ,oldname) ,arg)
      (error "Newname and Oldname need to be symbols")))

(defun-curried +xx + 20)
(+xx 10) ; ==> 30
```

`oldname` is taken from the lexical scope so you may use `flet` or `labels` with this but it ends up being global, just like with `defun`.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that `DEFUN` isn't a function, it's a macro that treats its arguments specially (specifically, it doesn't evaluate "the function name", "the argument list", not "the function body").

You could probably make something work by careful use of `(setf (symbol-function ...) ...)`, something like:

```
(defun define-custom-function (name op const)
   (setf (symbol-function name) (lambda (var) (funcall op const var))))
```

This binds the function definition of the symbol to an anonymous function that calls your "operator" on your fed-in constant.

```
* (defun define-custom-function (name op const)
       (setf (symbol-function name) (lambda (var) (funcall op const var))))

DEFINE-CUSTOM-FUNCTION
* (define-custom-function 'add3 #'+ 3)

#<CLOSURE (LAMBDA (VAR) :IN DEFINE-CUSTOM-FUNCTION) {1002A4760B}>
* (add3 5)

8
```

However, unless you absolutely need to define (or re-define) these custom functions dynamically, you are probably better off defining a custom `DEFUN`-like macro.